# How to do swipe gestures using selendroid web driver?

Tags: java, selendroid

1. I have tried with below codings for swiping a mobile pages.
2. While running the test case, the swipe action doesn't occurs and i am also not getting any error message.

3.How can I swipe on both side from left to right and vice-versa.

```
1. //Swipe Right to Left side of the Media Viewer First Page
                WebElement firstPages = driver.findElement(By.id("media-list"));
                TouchActions flick = new TouchActions(driver).flick(firstPages,-100,0,0);
                flick.perform();

2. //perform swipe gesture
               TouchActions swipe = new TouchActions(driver).flick(0, -20);
               swipe.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to flick pages and it is working fine for me

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            WebElement pages = driver.findElement(By.id("action_bar_overlay_layout"));
            TouchActions flick = new TouchActions(driver).flick(pages, 500, 0, 0);
            flick.perform();
        }
```

You can flick in both sides by just changing the sign of the x-parameter whose value is 500 here.